how to insert a gap in a title for pictures in Latex?

I want a gap between the BFH name of course and the picture
I tried to add a {}\\ in between or a \newline but it doesn't work.
Thanks
here is the code
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/pictures/}} %configuring the graphicx package

\title{\textbf{Assessment and retrofitting}\\
     {\large BFH name of course}\\
     {\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{images/pictures/global overview 1.jpg}}\\
     %try to create a gap in the picture
}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents 


Don't abuse \ for line breaks

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I don't understand your comment, how would you go around it ?

If you'd like to see how to add space, you should include a small, but compilable test document in your question. It should be posted as text and not as image.

You could use the titlepage environment to design the page however you want it:
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{\def\@subtitle{#1}}
\makeatother

\title{Assessment and retrofitting}
\subtitle{BFH name of course}
\author{names}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    \vfill
    {\bfseries\Large\@title\par}
    \vskip0.5cm
    {\large\@subtitle\par}
    \vskip1cm
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \vfill
    \@author
    \vfill
    \@date
    \vfill
    \vfill
\end{titlepage}
\makeatother

\end{document}


